# How can i create object from 2 arrays in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following two collections with their respective fields:

```
blogCollection : _id, blogId, description, date
images: _id, blogId, imageUrl, type
```

The data of images collection are like this

```
"images": [
    {
      "_id": "someid",
      "blogId": "blog2912201715021",
      "imageUrl":"https://someurl.com",
      "type":"Food"
    },
    {
      "_id": "someid",
      "blogId": "blog2912201782222",
      "imageUrl":"https://someurl.com",
      "type":"Adventure"
    },
    {
      "_id": "someid",
      "blogId": "blog2181881291131",
      "imageUrl":"https://someurl.com",
      "type":"Food"
    },
.........
```

I have following query

```
db.blogCollections.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            blogId: {'some_given_id'},
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'images',
            let: { bId: '$blogId' },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $or: [{ $eq: ['$blogId', '$$bId'] }],
                  },
                },
              },
              { $project: { _id: 0, imageUrl: 1 ,type:1} },
            ],
            as: 'image',
          },
        },
        {
          $set: {
// i want to add a new field called allImages of certain type in blog as array of imageUrls
// something like this [imageUrl1,imageUrl2,.........]
//           allImages: , 
          },
        },
      ]);
```

is there a way that i can use condition in set?
Suppose i want to add images to type 'Food', then i should store only the image urls of food type images.
Is it possible? I tried everything filter, cond and all but it doesn't work :/ ... Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
db.blogCollections.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        blogId: 'blog2912201715021',
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'images',
        let: { bId: '$blogId' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $or: [{ $eq: ['$blogId', '$$bId'] }],
              },
            },
          },
          { $project: { _id: 0, imageUrl: 1 ,type:1} },
        ],
        as: 'image'
      }
    },
    {$unwind: "$image"},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                blogId:"$blogId",
                type: "$image.type"
            },
        allImages: {
            $push: "$image.imageUrl"
        }
    }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: yeah although the result of this query can be manipulated easily to get my desired result... tq for ur answer